# Unexpected transparent gap between columns in a table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

There are some strange transparent gaps between columns in a table

[image]

Here is css

```
div.table-container{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color:colors.$lighter_blue;
position: relative;

div.table-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin; //for FireFox
    box-shadow: 0px 0 5px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);

    table.securities-table{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
              
        th,td{
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    
        tbody{
            tr:nth-child(odd){
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }         
        }      
    
        th{
            color: white;
            background-color: colors.$light-blue;
            text-align: left;
            position: sticky;
            top: -1px;
            z-index: 1;
        }   
    }
}
}
```

here is HTML

```
const securitiesTableHeader = () => {
    return (
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {securitiesHeader.map((header,i) => 
                <th key={header+i}>{header.headerName}</th>)
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    );
}

const securitiesTableCols = (row) => {
    return (
        securitiesHeader.map((header,i) =>
                <td key={row[header.value]+"_"+i}>
                    {getColumnValue(row, header.value)}
                </td>)
    )
}

const securitiesTableRows= () => {
    return (
        <tbody>
            {
                securitiesJSON.map((obj,i) =>
                <tr key={"row_"+i}>
                    {securitiesTableCols(obj)}
                </tr> 
            )}
        </tbody>
        );
}

return (
<div className = "table-container">
    <div className={`table-wrapper`}>
        <table className= {`securities-table`}>
            {securitiesTableHeader()}
            {securitiesTableRows()}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried border-collapse: collapse or separate with border-spacing: 0 but it couldn't remove those "transparent" gaps. Even weirder, those gaps appear and disappear randomly without any specific order/pattern. I only see that in Chrome in mobile view mode in Developer Tools(Chrome inspect) and as far as I know, I didn't see that from Firefox or Edge. I suspect that it is a bug from Chrome but I am quite sure. If anyone has seen this before, I appreciate if you could help me solve this.

Comment: I suspect the `position:sticky`. Try applying it to the entire `tr:first-child` rather than to `th`.

Comment: It didn't work :( Never seen this before. If you refresh, scroll horizontally, or change a screen size, the gaps sometimes disappear but appear in different columns. Very strange.

Comment: It's a bug in chrome. Please file with small reproduction case at http://crbug.com/new

Answer (score 0):

```
div.table-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin; //for FireFox

    table.securities-table{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
              
        th,td{
            padding: 5px;
        }
    
        tbody{
            tr:nth-child(odd){
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }         
        }      
    
        th{
            color: white;
            background-color: colors.$light-blue;
            text-align: left;
            top: -1px;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You helped me remove unnecessary positions from container and wrapper. Thanks, but just removing the positions and position sticky at th doesn't solve this problem.